# Cannot import SubfieldBase from django.db.models import SubfieldBase

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get rid of the error and couldn't find a clue how to fix it. Please advise because I've seen few fixes in different packages but none of them are relevant.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AliKhan\supermarekt\market\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in popu
late
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create

    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\AliKhan\supermarekt\market\catalogue\__init__.py", line 4, in
<module>
    from django.db.models import SubfieldBase
ImportError: cannot import name SubfieldBase
```

In my Catalouge package I've just simply imported it and import is getting failed.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db.models.fields import CharField, DecimalField
from django.db.models import SubfieldBase
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Django Source code for SubfieldBase is following that lies at djagno.db.models.subclassing.py for Django version 1.8.16.

```
import warnings

from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango110Warning


class SubfieldBase(type):
    """
    A metaclass for custom Field subclasses. This ensures the model's attribute
    has the descriptor protocol attached to it.
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        warnings.warn("SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead.",
                  RemovedInDjango110Warning, stacklevel=2)

        new_class = super(SubfieldBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class.contribute_to_class = make_contrib(
            new_class, attrs.get('contribute_to_class')
        )
        return new_class
```

Comment: Did you read the code you just posted? It has a very clear description of what's happened to that class.

Comment: But should it pop up import error?

Comment: In Django 1.10, yes.

Comment: Its 1.8.16 as mentioned above in the main question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird but it is happening more often now. In Windows 10 if I create virtualenv and install djagno version different than global installation it still servers attributes of global installation. I even tried with --no-site-packages but behavior is still same and its problematic. I removed 1.10 globally and now issues is fixed.